# ios icon transition effects on unlock

Tags: javascript, ios, css

Without the right `search term` I could not find what do you call that effect on ios devices.

Is there a library, tutorial, a fiddle that actually does that transition effects on icons upon unlock of the device, specifically done using css3 only or a little bit of javascript or atleast comment out what is the name of that effect.

If you can't imagine what I am saying, watch this [ios7 introduction in youtube](http://youtu.be/F0ErUMeT7uE?t=1m14s)

Comment: Where can i see in this video? atleast set the time here?

Comment: at least click the link,

Comment: i did that, it starts to unlock? and icons pop up....

Comment: that's what I am looking for, that transition animation of the icons as it aligns themselves on the grid

Comment: CSS3Generator has something like this. I have not been able to make a fiddle for it, but they have some jquery which adds a class to the elements which makes them ease out to a new position and give them opacity 0. # http://css3generator.com/

Comment: @andershagbard you sir, really deserve +1

Comment: You may want to reword your question, it currently reads a lot like a "off-topic... recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the search term your looking for would be transition and/or transform, if you're hoping to use css to accomplish the effect...

Here's a **[Simplified Example](http://jsfiddle.net/uJRA8/4/)** of how you could use a combination of transitions, transforms, and a touch of javascript to get where you're going:

CSS

```
.wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 255px;
    height: 255px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.container {
    width: 255px;
    height: 255px;
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease;
    transition: all 1.5s ease;
}
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 72px;
    height: 72px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease;
    transition: all 1.5s ease;
}
.fly .box {
    margin:50px;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-175px) translateY(-500px);
    transform: translateX(-175px) translateY(-500px);
    opacity: 0;
}
.fly .container {
    width:610px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease;
    transition: all 1.5s ease;
}
```

JS

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    $('.wrap').toggleClass('fly');
});
```

HTML

```
<button>Toggle fly</button>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the position of each individuel child when you throw the effect.
I made it with jQuery and CSS3. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uJRA8/2/

```
...

...

#container .box:nth-child(8) {
    top: 170px;
    left: 85px;
}
#container .box:nth-child(9) {
    top: 170px;
    left: 170px;
}

#container.fly .box:nth-child(1) {
    top: -75px;
    left: -75px;
}

...

...
```

Comment: +1 Nice approach, but using nth-child may be a little troublesome

Comment: Why would it be troublesome?

Comment: Using nth-child you have to add css for each "icon", its not as scalable.